# Non-unique name in ASP MVC when using .Where().FirstOrDefault() inside a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following ASP MVC RAZOR code:

```
@foreach (var prod in Model.allProducts)
{   
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion2" href="#collapse@(i)">
                <h4 class="widgettitle" id="Title">> @prod.Description_VC</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse@(i)" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="accordion-inner" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <strong>Total for product:</strong> 
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.OfferHeaders.Where(p => p.Product_ID == prod.Product_ID).FirstOrDefault().Amount_DEC)
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    @{i++;}
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
}
```

But the HTML that gets generated for each of the TextBoxFor controls has the same name of `Amount_DEC` and as a result, when i try to post the form back, all the properties in my viewmodel is null. How do i ensure that my HTML controls get uniquely names so that the model binder can use them in the POST?

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I was having trouble getting it right due to the stupid Mac keyboard.

Comment: Why not use o.OfferHeaders.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Product_ID == prod.Product_ID).Amount_DEC). Why whould you call Where() if you can pass your predicate in the SingleOrDefault function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to replace you TextBoxFor code with the following:

```
@for (int j = 0; j < o.OfferHeaders.Count(); j++)
{
    if (o.OfferHeaders[j].Product_ID == prod.Product_ID)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.OfferHeaders[j].Amount_DEC)
        break;
    }
}
```

It's not the best solution, but it should work in your case.

Comment: Im going to give this a try now. When you say, "its not the best solution", what would you suggest to improve?

Comment: I mean that it won't be the fastest method to generate the TextBox. If you change the structure of you view you could improve it, but with the current structure I'm not sure whether it's possible to have a faster way to generate the textbox.

Comment: If i rejigged the view such that i could pass the result of the Where().FirstOrDefault() into an EditorTemplate for each iteration of the loop, do you think the rendering engine would generate the unique object names?

Comment: I don't think so. If you go with this approach in your EditorTemplate you'll have to implement the Approach that Sergio explained.

Comment: I have made this change, and although it is now generating unique names (happy), my submit button has stopped working (not happy). The POST method on the controller is not being called.

Comment: I saw what is the problem. You've already used the i variable in the code. Replace the i variable in my loop with j for example and it should fix your problem.

Comment: I have tried this and still get absolutely no response from the Submit button. No javascript errors in the console, no breakpoint hit on the post method on the server.

Comment: Could you please show us the whole code of your View.

Comment: The problem for this question was resolved by using ssimeonovs answer above. I will open a new question for the submit button problem.

Comment: Just as a final comment, I (kind of) followed ssimeonov's unwritten advice and re-thought out my ViewModel and View. It's all much better now. Many thanks to everyone who took the time to help me out with this.

Answer (score 2):

If your method expects model as `IEnumerable<...>` you could use `Html.TextBox` helper instead of `Html.TextBoxFor`:

```
@Html.TextBox(string.Format("ModelName[{0}].ModelField", i), yourValueHere)
```

assuming your model name is `ModelName` and it has property `ModelField`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.OfferHeaders
                       .Where(p => p.Product_ID == prod.Product_ID)
                       .FirstOrDefault().Amount_DEC, 
                 //unique name set here
                 new { Name = "txt1" })
```

Comment: Why whould you call Where() if you can pass your predicate in the SingleOrDefault function?